# Can you explain this Bresenham's Circle implementation?

Tags: c++, bresenham

I'm studying a paper in which the author claims to use Bresenham circles to scan the area around a pixel efficiently. I studied the algorithm but the equations used in most websites I've seen are way different from the author's implementation. Have a look:

```
//center(center.x,center.y) is the circle's center pixel. 
int err = 0;
int dx = _radius;
int dy = 0;
int plus = 1;
int minus = (_radius << 1) - 1;
int olddx = dx;

while (dx>=dy){
    int mask;
    int y=center.y-dy;
    int x=center.x-dx;
    //Found p(x,y).
    //Pixel operations here, not included, not relevant...
    //

    //Now the update. How do they check whether to decrease dx or not??
    dy++;
    err += plus;
    plus += 2;
    
    mask = (err <= 0) - 1;
    
    err -= minus & mask;
    dx += mask;
    minus -= mask & 2;
}
```

I understand that we only find the pixels of one octant. I understand that we start from (center.x-radius,center.y). So, as we travel along the corresponding octant, dy always increases but dx needs to pass a test to decrease. I've been trying to figure out how the test is done here but with no luck.

`plus, minus, mask, err`

What do these represent? Any ideas? It's either a simplification of Bresenham's circle algorithm for a faster scan with less computations or a completely different one?

I think I can only understand how `mask` is defined. If the error `err`(which we usually have formulas for) is negative, dx stays the same according to the Bresenham algorithm. `mask` makes sure this is the case here as well.  As for how the error is calculated here and how it's connected to `plus` and `minus`, I have no idea.

Comment: I feel that this is some hacky C code for normal algorithm. If there is no answer within next two weeks I'll try solve it.